# TransactionAmount problems!

Tags: orders, price, tax, sales-order

Hello is it possible to get the 'price' without shipping & tax?

$transactionAmount = $order->getData('price');

Comment: have you tried `$order->getGrandTotal() - $order->getTaxAmount()` ?

Comment: @JulienLachal Tried it now, didnt work :(

Comment: @JulienLachal you ment so the line will be like this?

$transactionAmount = $order->getGrandTotal() - $order->getTaxAmount();

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: @JulienLachal

Still problems :( wont work, tried so many different commands now

Comment: have you tried debugging like so : `var_dump($order->getData());`
Then you'll be able to figure out what to call, or what to add/sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order object includes both subtotal and subtotal_incl_tax. Looking at the object subtotal is indeed without tax and without the shipping costs.

You can use:

```
$order->getSubtotal();
```